# how to use is()

Tags: jquery

How to refactor the follow to put **NOT is(":checked")** syntax, instead put the codes being executed in the else block?

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    // do nothing
}
else {
    // To do here
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You do not need jQuery for this. [See here](http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would add a negation (`!`) to it, like this:

```
if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
```

But you can just use the [`checked` DOM property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) directly here, which is much faster:

```
if (!this.checked) {
```

Comment: `!this.checked` is probably better, no point round-tripping it through jQuery just to get a value that's already available through the DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this, or am I missing something?

```
if( $(this).is(":checked") == false) 
{
    // To do here
}
```